# Spread elements of rows to multiple rows

Tags: matlab, split, adjacency-matrix, edges

I am working on graph theory using adjacency matrix, I want to split the edges between multiple nodes for instance I have the following initial adjacency matrix :

```
    a= [ 0 2 3;
         2 0 1;
         3 1 0]
```

From that matrix its clear that we have 3 nodes, Now I want to split the aforementioned rows (edges) into new random nodes between (1-3) :

```
 split= randi([1 3],1,length(A));
 split = [ 2 2 1]
```

I know now that I need to split the elements of the first row into two rows, the elements of the second rows also into two rows, while the elements of th third row will remain as is, and I'll have new matrix with size 5X5 as following:

```
    A = [0 0 2 0 3;
         0 0 0 0 0;
         2 0 0 0 1;
         0 0 0 0 0;
         3 0 1 0 0]
```

What I want to do is to split the non-zero elements in the first row between this row and the second row, and the third with the fourth, so my matrix will look like:

```
    An = [0 0 2 0 0;
          0 0 0 0 3;
          2 0 0 0 0;
          0 0 0 0 1;
          0 3 0 1 0]
```

Comment: So if `split  = [3 3 3]` then `An` will be a `[9 x 9]` matrix. Right?

Comment: @rahnema1  Exactly!

Comment: Shouldn't the matrix diagonal be 0?

Comment: @rahnema1 yes it is all the time after and before splitting

Comment: Sorry but... what is the criterion for moving the non-zero values of a row up and down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not fully clear to me what's the initial point, the prerequisites and conditions. I assume that every second row/column is a row/column of zeros. I furthermore assume that the non-zero rows/columns have exactly two non-zero values whereas the second value should be moved to the next row/column. For this, I'd suggest:

```
A = [0 0 2 0 3 ; 0 0 0 0 0 ; 2 0 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 0 0 ; 3 0 1 0 0];

for n = 1:2
    if n==2
        A = A';
    end % if
    for k = 1:2:size(A,1)-1
        m = find(A(k,:));
        A(k+(0:1),m(end)) = flipud(A(k+(0:1),m(end)));
    end % for
    if n==2
        A = A';
    end % if
end % for

A

A =

     0     0     2     0     0
     0     0     0     0     3
     2     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     3     0     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, and I have edited my question to have more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here `An` is directly generated from `a` without creating `A`:

```
a = [ 0 2 3;
      2 0 1;
      3 1 0];

split = [ 2 2 1];

L = length(a);
cum = cumsum([1 split(1:end-1)]);

%ro = rot90(split - (0:L-1).' + cum-1, -1); %MATLAB R2016b
ro = rot90(bsxfun(@minus,split + cum-1 , (0:L-1).') , -1);
co = repmat(cum, L, 1);
idx = triu(true(L), 1);

N =  sum(split);
An = zeros(N);
sub = sub2ind([N,N], ro(idx), co(idx));
An(sub) = a(idx);
An = An + An.'

An =
0   0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0   3
2   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1
0   3   0   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried running it for bigger metrices and it gave me th followong error:  error using sub2ind out of range subscript

Comment: You should determine how to split a row. For example how do you split `[ 3 4 5 6 2]` into two parts?